# Filtered Query with Term on collection

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm taking an old project to maintain and I am stuck since a day on a query.
The elasticsearch version I use is 1.7 but I don't think this is relevant to my problem.

I have some teacher documents :

```
{
  "id": 244,
  "degree": [],
  "teacherDiplomaRelation": [],
  "user": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "teacherClassDisciplineRelation": [
    SEE BELOW
}
```

The teacherClassDisciplineRelation is **N times** this format (for every couple levelTree/Discipline that I have)

```
{
  "levelTree": {
    "id": 34,
    "label": "1st year of college",
    "slugLastLevelDisplay": "college"
  },
  "discipline": {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Maths",
    "slug": "maths"
  },
  "cityLocation": "10.1010,10.1010"
}
```

Now i want to get all teacher enabled and having maths in their disciplines. my query is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user.enabled": true
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "teacherClassDisciplineRelation.discipline.slug": "maths"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 15
  }
}
```

Mapping:

```
    "teacherClassDisciplineRelation": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "cityLocation": {
            "type": "geo_point",
            "store": true
          },
          "discipline": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": true
              },
              "label": {
                "type": "string",
                "boost": 7.0,
                "store": true,
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
              },
              "slug": {
                "type": "string",
                "boost": 7.0,
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "store": true,
                "norms": {
                  "enabled": true
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

**Problem:**
My query with `"user.enabled": true` give me some results,
My query with `"teacherClassDisciplineRelation.discipline.slug": "maths"` **always gives me 0 result** but I've checked in the index, **I should have some results**.

I'm new to elasticsearch but I can't find out why my result is always 0.
Any idea why?

Comment: please share the mapping. `GET index_name/type_name/_mapping`

Comment: @Richa I've just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `teacherClassDisciplineRelation` is a nested field. You have to use [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "nested": {
              "path": "teacherClassDisciplineRelation",
              "query": {
                 "term": {
                    "teacherClassDisciplineRelation.discipline.slug": {
                       "value": "maths"
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "term": {
              "user.enabled": true
             }
          }
       ]
    }
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks! I had to use the nested filter instead of the nested query, but your example helps me well. Specially the path was unclear to me.

Comment: Happy to help!!